# Algorithm for subdivision of 3D surfaces

Tags: c++, geometry, voronoi, q-learning

**Background**

I have a 3D scene, and I want to discretize the space of it so that every coordinate `(x, y, z)` belongs to a specific cell. 
 Coordinates close to each other belongs to same cells. When I input a coordinate that lies on the surface of one of my tridimensional objects (mainly spheres), I need to retrieve the cell it belongs to.
For those familiar with Reinforcement learning, this operation will be used for Q-Learning, to map states (cells depending on coordinates) to Q-values 
This is an example of what i am trying to achieve:

[image]

**Possible solutions**

I know that Voronoi diagram can help in this, but I also read that implementing it from scratch is complicated. I found some libraries in C++ to handle this, but they are mainly Voronoi 2D ([CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/)).
I don't specifically need Voronoi, I only need to discretize the space in a reasonable way and looking for libraries/implementation for it I stumbled upon Voronoi diagrams.

**Question**
Is there anyone familiar with libraries or a public implementation to achieve this discretization in C++?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I have edited to make my question explicit

Comment: too be superpicky: I am almost certain that the question you wrote is not the quesiton you want to have answered. Is there anyone familiar with...? - Yes. I think you can be more specific ;)

Comment: @user463035818 I agree! I was also very tempted to answer only a "Yes" below, but I refrained ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on you requirements, there may be many solutions. The simplest I can think of is to partition your space using a uniform grid. Then, the cell of a point `(x,y,z)` is simply `(floor(x),floor(y),floor(z))`. You can scale the coordinates to have get finer grid. If you need to have a single index, use a hash function or index all cells of a finite grid inside a bounding box. No libraries required, but it is not adaptive to the amount of points in an area.

Voronoï diagrams are another possible solution, but they are a lot more complicated to implement if you want the exact shape of all cells. If you only need to find the nearest site point, use Kd-Trees since they are a lot simpler to implement and gives you the information you need. You can find an implementation of both of these algorithms in [GEOGRAM](http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/index.html), a free and open (you can use it in commercial applications) C++ libraries for doing fast geometric computations. It works quite well and it is easy to use. It is also portable, it works on Linux, Windows, Mac OSX and Android.